# Can I do execute function during recording audio signal in MATLAB?

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I would like to get the pitch of frame of audio data during recording the signal. (without stop recording)
Firstly, I executed following code.

```
r = audiorecorder(fs,16,1);
while 1
   recordblocking(r,T);  % T is frame length [s]   (A)
   sample{k} = getaudiodata(r);   
   pitch{k} = get_pitch(sample{k});     % (B)
end
```

However, recording procedure stop during get_pitch function is executed, and it causes 
missing some part of music signal to be recorded.

I want the sample recording is executed without stop, but send data of length T[s] to the function get_pitch so that pitch of all the frame is obtained continuously.

Is there anyone who can give me some advice? I really appreciate all of your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you are using Matlab, and you want multi-threading, your only hope is the Parallel computing toolbox. 
What you have here is a typical `consumer/producer scenario` - Try to google for it.

However, the problem with your approach is not necessarily lack of threads. If the get_pitch command was fast enough, you would have had no problem. You might as well save all of the samples and do the analysis afterwards (If it fits in the application).

Comment: Unfortunately, my 'get_pitch'function is not that fast. But anyway, thanks!The link you give to me may helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: @gmkim90, welcome to SO. No need to thank, upvote and accept instead if the answer is helpful.